# LINQ - Method vs Query Syntax Difference

Tags: c#, linq, linq-query-syntax, linq-method-syntax

I was working with a DataTable and noticed that Resharper recommended that I can convert a loop into a LINQ expression. I did so and it was rewritten in query expression syntax (simplified):

```
var test1 = from DataRow row in dt.Rows select row;
```

Personally, I prefer method syntax so rewrote it to this:

```
var test2 = dt.Rows.Select(row => row);
```

And it broke.

> 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no 
>   extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Since query expression are [translated to method calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx), why is that the first works but not the second? I expected either both or neither to work which is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first has an explicitly typed range variable, so it's actually compiled to:

```
var test2 = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
```

(There's no need for the `Select` as this is a *degenerate query expression* (the select is a no-op.)

An alternative is to call [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) from [`DataTableExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.aspx). I believe there may be *some* performance benefits in that, but only in some cases:

```
var test2 = dt.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Which is necessary because `DataRowCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @ChrisShouts: Ah, I'd noticed this before but never quite twigged exactly why. The fact it implements the "wrong" IEnumerable is what I was missing. :)